# How to detect if a page is rendered in an iframe that allows fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to detect, with JavaScript, if my code is running in a cross-origin `iframe` that has `allowfullscreen="true"`.

Simple use case: I have a full-screen button that I'd like to only show if the `iframe` can be taken full-screen, but I have not found a great way to detect this!

Answer (score 1):

This was simple after all :). Here is a cross-browser solution:

```
const getFullscreenEnabled = () =>
  document.fullscreenEnabled ||
  document.webkitFullscreenEnabled ||
  document.mozFullScreenEnabled ||
  document.msFullscreenEnabled
```